# Searching HTML TD with Key Words

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to locate values in HTML TDs. I have read a lot and tried variations but its not clicking.

This is my HTML document

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; background-color:#eff7e8;" link="#3333ff" vlink="#3333ff" alink="#3333ff" topmargin="16" leftmargin="20">



<font color="#1984a8" style="font-size: 14pt">Property Details</font>

     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; " bordercolor="#111111" width="1000px" height="60px" id="AutoNumber1" bordercolorlight="#693A4A" bordercolordark="#693A4A" height="1">
        
    <tr>
        <td height="1" style="padding: 2; " valign="bottom"> 

<font color=#000000 style="font-size: 12pt">Number of records found: &nbsp;</font><b><font style="font-size: 12pt; color: #FF0000">1</b></font>
&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        
    <tr>
        <td height="1" style="padding: 2; " valign="top" width="100%" colspan="2"> 
<font align="justify" face="Arial" style="font-size: 10pt"><p align="justify">

One record is displayed for each address found at the selected property. Multiple addresses may occur in the case of condominiums.<br><br>

</p></font></td>
    </tr>
        
    </table>





<TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=1 style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt"><tr><TD align=center width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff style='border: 1px solid #ededed'><font style='font-size: 11pt'><b>1250 TRUMBULL HWY</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><br><font style='font-size: 10pt'>ID:&nbsp;<b><font style='font-size: 10pt'>250-10</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font style='font-size: 10pt'>Book:&nbsp;<b><font style='font-size: 10pt'>0311</b></font><font style='font-size: 10pt'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Page:&nbsp;<b><font style='font-size: 10pt'>1063</b></font></td><TD width=412 align='center'><a target='_blank' href='recordcard.asp?TY=0&ID=2732&PID=250-10'> <b>Property Card</b> </a><br></td></tr><tr><TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>ALTERNATE ID: <b>250-10</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>ACCOUNT NUMBER: <b>R0141550</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>PARCEL ID: <b>250-10</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>LOCATION: <b>1250 TRUMBULL HWY</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>BUILDING ASSESSMENT: <b>70120</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>IMPROVEMENTS ASSESSMENT: <b>71980</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>LAND ASSESSMENT: <b>19140</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>OTHER BUILDING ASSESSMENT: <b>880</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>EXTRA FEATURES ASSESSMENT: <b>980</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>TOTAL ASSESSMENT: <b>91120</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>PRIOR TOTAL ASSESSMENT: <b>91120</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>LAST SALE DATE: <b>2019-05-03 00:00:00.0000000</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>BOOK: <b>0311</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>PAGE: <b>1063</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>LAST SALE VALUE: <b>95000</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>OWNER: <b>SEIDL DAVID D</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>CO-OWNER: <b></b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>MAILING ADDRESS LINE 1: <b>82 BASCOM RD</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>MAILING ADDRESS CITY: <b>LEBANON</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>MAILING ADDRESS STATE: <b>CT</b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>MAILING ADDRESS ZIP: <b>06249</b></TD>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>MAILING ADDRESS LINE 2: <b></b></TD></tr><tr>
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ffffff>MAILING ADDRESS LINE 3: <b></b></TD>
<TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><TD width=412>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr></tr><tr></TABLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
if (document.body.scrollHeight < 800) {parent.document.getElementById('frame_b').height = 800} else {parent.document.getElementById('frame_b').height = document.body.scrollHeight;}</SCRIPT>

</body>

</html>
```

I am looking to extract parcel information

```
<TD width=412 bgcolor=#ededed>BOOK: <b>0311</b></TD>
```

From what I saw from people online and various iterations that is what I have come up with but I still get a blank list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('http://www.mainstreetmaps.com/ct/lebanon/property.asp?TY=0&PID=250-10')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
a = soup.findAll('td', text = "BOOK")
```

The website I used is here: http://www.mainstreetmaps.com/ct/lebanon/property.asp?TY=0&PID=250-10

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @ Jack Fleeting In the example for BOOK. I would like to reference BOOK and have 0311 returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for book in soup.select('td'):
    if 'BOOK' in book.text:
        print(book.select_one('b').text)
```

Output:

```
0311
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without a for loop using `regex` and `find`

The following returns the value found after book, enclosed by `<b>`.

```
soup.find(string=re.compile('BOOK:')).find_next_sibling('b').text

#'0311'
```

Comment: Thats even better!
Thank you again. Your have given me more information to use and expand on